# Problema en count php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

No tengo error en la conexión , pero no me muestra correctamente el numero de ticket's pendientes que estoy viendo en el sistema, intente con cambiar los valores de `tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1` a otro pero me sigue mostrando `1`.

**Código: `PHP`**

```
function pendientesporrevisar($conexion){    
    $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket
                                             WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1 ")) 
                   or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));    
    return $pendientes;
}
```

**Código `HTML`:**

```
<?php echo $ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion)->field_count; ?>
```

Comment: Esa SQL no parece correcta: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and.php sería más bien AND y no &&

Comment: es posible ver un conjunto de datos de prueba sobre los que corre tu ejemplo y la salida esperada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsÍ lo hice yo , en mi clase ticket , agregue la siguiente función .

```
function pendientesporrevisar($conexion){

    $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1 ")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    $resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($pendientes);
    return $resultados[0];

}
```

Probada antes con el phpmyadmin de mi hosting trayendome la cuenta de los tickets creados que tuvieran el tipo de solicitud = 1 y el status = 1.

Lo que hice despues fue llamarlos en mi codigo html para mostrarlo .

```
<div align="left" >TICKETS DE ANULACION PENDIENTES POR ATENDER:<?php echo $ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion);/* los de anulacion*/ ?>
```

Disculpen si fue muy enredado , apenas estoy empezando y me encuentro con algo difícil de analizar en el trabajo (un sistema hecho por una persona muy buena en programación). Gracias a todos por la ayuda e interes.

Answer (score 7):

Posiblemente el problema esté en la sintaxis de la consulta, tú estas usando el `&&`:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1 "
```

y deberías usar `AND`:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 AND status = 1 "
```

Puedes leer más sobre el formato de consultas **MySql** [aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm)

Comment: hola @Levi Arista, puedes decirme por que deberia usar el AND, en vez del &&?

Comment: Se puede utilizar el operador lógico `&&` en MySQL, [mira](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and)

Answer (score 3):

Posible error de sintaxis:

```
function pendientesporrevisar($conexion){


$pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 AND status = 1 ")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $pendientes;
}
```

**simple reemplaza && POR (AND)**

Comment: hola @Diego Avila , puedes decirme por que deberia usar el AND en vez del &&?

Answer (score 3):

Solamente para que sepas por qué tu código no funcionaba de la manera esperada: **por el simple hecho de que estabas usando [`field_count`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.field-count.php)** el cual:

> Devuelve el número de columnas para la consulta más reciente

De hecho, tu código era este:

<s>`<?php echo $ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion)->field_count; ?>`</s>

y te devolvía siempre `1` porque estabas recuperando el número de columnas, no el valor de las mismas.

De todos modos, es bueno estandarizar el código SQL, usando `AND` en vez de `&&`, aunque funcione de las dos maneras.

En cualquier caso, **el problema estaba en la lectura de la información que estabas implementando**.

Es importante saber que hay varias formas de obtener los resultados, mediante los diferentes métodos `fetch`. Quizá, para que el código quede más legible, conviene usar [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), pongo un ejemplo para ampliar el abanico de posibilidades:

```
function pendientesporrevisar($conexion){

    $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1 ")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    $resultados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pendientes);
    $total = ($resultados && $resultados["conteo"]>0) ? $resultados["conteo"] : NULL ;
    return $total;

}
```

En la función también he añadido un control suplementario: usando un operador ternario someto a evaluación el intento de obtención de los datos, asigno a la variable `$total` el resultado obtenido o bien `NULL`, en caso de que haya algún problema... El valor `NULL` puede ser sustituido por `0`, por una cadena en blanco `''` o por otra cosa si así lo prefieres.

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta.