# filtrar con if php y mostrar solo si es mayor a 0

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Con esta función creo la busqueda de mis pendientes.

```
function pendientesporrevisar($conexion){

        $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1 ")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
        $resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($pendientes);
        return $resultados[0];

    }
```

Lo importo luego a mi html y lo muestro asi

```
<div align="" class="">PENDIENTES:<?php echo '<div class="notificacion">', $ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion),'</div>'; ?></div>
```

¿Cómo puedo mostrar el número solo si es mayor a 0? 
Es decir, que no me muestre un 0.

Comment: podrias mostrar que trae $resultados[0]

Comment: ¿Necesitas los registros cuyo número sea igual a 0 en el lado de PHP? Si no, quizás podrías plantearte usar un `having` en la consulta.

Comment: Juan, si implementas el [operador ternario, como te explico aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/157017/29967), sólo cambia esta línea: `$total = ($resultados) ? $resultados["conteo"] : 0 ;` por esto: **`$total = ($resultados && $resultados["conteo"] > 0) ? $resultados["conteo"] : '' ;`**   o por esto: **`$total = ($resultados && $resultados["conteo"] > 0) ? $resultados["conteo"] : NULL ;`** y listo, no tendrás que hacer nada más.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, no , no los nececesito, ya investigo que es un having, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta almecenando el resultado en una variable el resultado y para luego hacer la comprobacion si es mayor:

```
<?php

 $resultado = $ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion);

 if($resultado > 0) // validamos si es mayor a 0
{
?>
   <div align="" class="">PENDIENTES:<?php echo '<div 
   class="notificacion">',$resultado,'</div>'; ?></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Gracias , esto hace precisamente lo que necesitaba. Manito arriba , ah no ,eso es facebook ,  check verde para ti , Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar operadores ternarios como te muestro en la siguiente linea, he declarado una variable para que el código sea mas legible:

```
<?php 
    $totalPendiente = $ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion);
?>
<div align="" class="">PENDIENTES:
   <?php echo '<div class="notificacion">', 
     $totalPendiente ? $totalPendiente : '' ,
   '</div>'; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

podrias usar algo como esto:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1");

    if(mysqli_fetch_array($result) !== false)
        return 'notificaciones';//hacer lo que deseas !!
```

es una forma que podrias realizarlo.. espero haberte ayudado y suerte !!

Comment: no lo entendi @Diego Avila , si el resultado de la consulta no es igual a nada , regresa las notificaciones?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes determinarlo en la función de origen.

Algo así:

```
function pendientesporrevisar($conexion){

        $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 AND status = 1 ")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
        $resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($pendientes);
        $total = ($resultados && $resultados[0] > 0) ? $resultados[0] : '' ;
        return $total;

    }
```

El operador ternario devolverá el total cuando éste sea mayor que `0` o una cadena en blanco. Además, controlaría cualquier error debido al uso de `mysqli_fetch_row`. También puedes devolver `NULL` en lugar de una cadena en blanco (`NULL` no se imprime en pantalla y podría servir para cualquier otra evaluación en otro contexto):

```
        $total = ($resultados && $resultados[0] > 0) ? $resultados[0] : NULL ;
```

Así, no necesitas manipular de nuevo el código en la llamada, escribiéndolo tal cual:

```
<div align="" class="">PENDIENTES:<?php echo '<div class="notificacion">', $ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion),'</div>'; ?></div>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: gracias, ese es el resultado Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\sistemas\helpdesk\clases\ticket.class.php on line 80

Comment: @JuanOrtiz  Yo había puesto el código basado en la anterior respuesta. Ahora está adaptado a tu método `mysqli_fetch_row`. Revisa de nuevo la respuesta y pruébalo así... o cambia todo a `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. La otra respuesta también la edité, de cualquiera de las dos formas que lo hagas debería funcionar.